# logrotate: did not compress file

Tags: logging, logrotate

Here is my custum logrotate file

```
/var/log/mysite/uwsgi.log {
    daily
    missingok
    rotate 10
    compress
    notifempty
    copytruncate
}
```

And I check the result today:

```
-rw-r-----.  1 root     root     74441041 12月  2 13:13 uwsgi.log
-rw-r-----.  1 root     root     72226790 12月  2 03:44 uwsgi.log-20151202
```

I did not set `delaycompress`,but why it did not compress it???
Should I need to do something after edit the file?

Answer (score 2):

Option `compress` compresses old files. It is ok that you have two uncompressed files.
With you config you will get 1 original uncompressed file + one last rotated uncompressed file + 9 compressed files.